# Don't spider certain pages on multiple domains same hosting

Tags: .htaccess, web-crawler, robots.txt

I have a hosting account with 2 domains parked on it, the websites shows different content by reading which domain is being used.

Google will spider this and list the 2 domains as different websites.

*So we have these listed on Google:-

www.blue.com/index.php

www.pink.com/index.php*

Then lets say I have another page I only want on the blue domain: www.blue.com/test.php, as the domains are parked this will still work at www.pink.com/test.php

This means it will get spidered, which I don't want it to do.

How can I stop this?

Is it possible to have multiple htaccess rules depending on the domain? Or maybe a robots.txt to stop the spidering - how would that work with the multiple domains?

What is the best solution for me?

Answer (score 1):

Redirect to different domain specific robots_(blue|pink).txt in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_write.c>

  RewriteEngine on

  # internal redirect to robots_blue.txt
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.blue.com
  RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots_blue.txt [L]

  # internal redirect to robots_pink.txt
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.pink.com
  RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots_pink.txt [L]

  # internal redirct to index_blue.php, rewrite internal only 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.blue.com
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index_blue.php [L]  # or "... /index.php?site=blue"

  # external permanent redirect of test.php to index.php if not www.blue.com  
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.blue.com
  RewriteRule ^test\.php$ /index.php [L,R=301] 

  # internal redirect
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.pink.com
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index_pink.php [L]
```

robots_blue.txt, don't crawl test.php in www.blue.com:

```
User-agent: *
Sitemap: http://www.blue.com/sitemap.xml

Disallow: /test.php
Disallow: ...
```

robots_pink.txt, crawling allowed in www.pink.com:

```
User-agent: *
Sitemap: http://www.blue.com/sitemap.xml

Disallow:
```

If Disallows of www.blue.com are identical to www.pink.com, just use robots_blue.txt as robots.txt for both domains. It should work if there is no test.php used in www.pink.com.

But if sitemap.xml to be used in robots.txt too this should be a solution.